# PostSharp and project.json

Tags: postsharp, project.json

Is there any way to specify an absolute path in the SearchPath property of PostSharp?

My solution is using project.json for our NuGet packages and it stores all of the packages in your user profile (`%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages`).

I've tried entering that into the "Additional search path" setting on the projects, but it fails with the error "`Invalid path passed to PostSharp (SearchPath element)"` because it just appends it to the solution directory.

Alternatively, does anyone know of another way to have PostSharp play nicely with project.json files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET Core is not supported by the current version of PostSharp (4.x). So, unfortunately you cannot fix the issue by only editing the settings.

The support for .NET Core is coming in PostSharp 5.0.

Comment: Indeed, I've had to remove the usage of PostSharp because of this. I will give it another try once version 5.0 is out.